# how to get name from a table corresponding to the id taken from different table in zend framework

Tags: sql, zend-framework

i written a query in php zend framework where i joined three table employee, products, bid.
in product table i have a column buyer, where am saving buyer employee id, and am displaying details of sellername(taken from employee nname, column name ename, ) and also need to display buyer name by taking buyer id from the product table and matching ename from employee table. 
my sql query is given below.
except the above feature its working fine.

```
$oSelect = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
            ->joinLeft(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
            ->joinInner(array("e" => "employees"), "e.employee_id=p.employee_id",array('ename'))
            ->where("p.verified = ?", "Yes")
            ->where("p.sold_out = ?", "Yes")
            ->group('p.product_id')
            ->having("p.sale_end_date >= ?", date("Y-m-d"));
```

so anyone help me to add the above feature to this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select query will be like this for displaying buyername

$oSelect = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
            ->joinLeft(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
            ->joinLeft(array("e" => "employees"), "e.employee_id=p.employee_id",array('ename'))
->joinLeft(array("e1" => "employees"), "e1.employee_id=p.buyer_id",array('buyer_name' => 'ename'))
            ->where("p.verified = ?", "Yes")
            ->where("p.sold_out = ?", "Yes")
            ->group('p.product_id')
            ->having("p.sale_end_date >= ?", date("Y-m-d"));
```